# ember.js update view after PUT using node.js/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, express, coffeescript

I'm pretty new to ember. I have a basic ember app in place with a CRUD page. I'm having trouble refreshing the view/template of the CRUD page after making a PUT request to a node API using mongoDB.

When I delete a model, the page refreshes fine, but not when I PUT. If I refresh the page, everything is fine and working, but I want the view to refresh as soon as I click the "approve" button I have.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how I should be dealing with this in Ember? Or am I not returning something properly from my API and Ember is doing what it should?

Thanks

Node API PUT:

```
router.put( '/:id', function( req, res ) {
  return Picture.findById( req.params.id, function( err, picture ) {

    picture.status = req.body.picture.status;
    picture.url = req.body.picture.url;
    //...and so on

    return picture.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) { return res.send( picture ); }
        return res.send('ERROR');
    });
  });
});
```

Model:

```
App.Picture = DS.Model.extend
  authorName: DS.attr('string')
  pictureName: DS.attr('string')
  url: DS.attr('string')
  tags: DS.attr('string')
  status: DS.attr('string')
```

Route:

```
App.AdminRoute = Ember.Route.extend

      model: ->
        return @store.find 'picture'

      actions:

        delete: (picture) ->
          picture.destroyRecord() # view updates fine

        approve: (picture) ->
            picture.set('status', 'verified')
            picture.save()
```

Note - I'm also getting this error in my console that I have no understanding of - I don't remember always getting it though, so I'm not sure how much it's related.

```
Error: No model was found for 'v'
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.r (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-1.7.0.js:4:992)
    at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:3:4754)
    at t.default.i.extend.extractSingle (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:1:23642)
    at y (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-1.7.0.js:4:30411)
    at r [as extractSingle] (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-1.7.0.js:4:28863)
    at e.default.Ember.Object.extend.extractSave (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:1:22390)
    at e.default.Ember.Object.extend.extractUpdateRecord (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:1:22097)
    at e.default.Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:1:21661)
    at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/libs/ember-data.js:3:9807
```

Comment: What does the payload of the response to the `PUT` look like?

Comment: Use the Chrome debugger and look at the Network section.  Click on the request in question and then the "response" tab.  You should see a JSON response that Ember is trying to parse.  My guess is it contains an element (maybe the root) that starts with a `v` :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining Steve! Dang though, looks like the returning JSON is good though. The property I changed was "status" from unverified to verified:
{"_id":"5428abf33e733af2fc0007ff","authorName":"Ben","pictureName":"Proud Chicken","status":"verified","tags":null,"url":"http://benrlodge.github.io/isotopeSearchFilter/img/four.jpg"}

Answer (score 0):

The JSON payload being returned from the server is not in a format suitable for Ember to determine the model type.  Ember is expecting something like this:

```
{
    picture: {
        "_id":"5428abf33e733af2fc0007ff","authorName":"Ben","pictureName":"Proud Chicken",
        "status":"verified","tags":null,"url":"benrlodge.github.io/isotopeSearchFilter/img/four.jpg"
    }
}
```

Since you say it works when you refresh, try comparing this payload with what is returned from the `GET`.  The `PUT` response should be similar.

Refer to this Ember guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions

To tweak the payload and (for example) remove the offending property, you can do this:

```
App.PictureSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        if (payload['__v']) {
            delete payload['__v'];
        }
        return this._super(payload);
    }
});
```

This example is for `PictureSerializer`, but if you made it `ApplicationSerializer` it would work for any type.  See the API here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing out  - I adjusted my PUT response to return in the Ember convention. It still doesn't update though...I also now see that "v" you mentioned, not sure why it's only showing up now (even when I changed back to just res.send( picture ) it shows the v). Anyways, here is how I have the response returning but no luck:  
`{ "picture":
  {
    "__v":0,"_id":"542af500bc85c675bbbd49c0",
    "authorName":"ben",
    "pictureName":"Dog Hair",
    "status":"verified",
    "tags":"dog, dog hair",
    "url":"http://benrlodge.github.io/isotopeSearchFilter/img/seven.jpg"
  }
}
`

Comment: I just noticed that "No model was found for 'v'" only occurs on some of my records. I just tried updating another record and it said "No model was found for 'id'". Maybe this has something to do with MongoDB prepending the id with and underscore? I did add the primaryKey: "_id" to the ApplicationSerializer to fix an earlier issue I had with that. FWIW I learned the "__v" has to do with mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey), still don't know if that's causing my issue here thought but figured I would mention.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I tried using your normalizePayload function but I get "hash is not defined". Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `payload`, not `hash`.  I have corrected my answer.